# When sending POST data via MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, are input names required?

Tags: php, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I have a company wanting to send POST data to a URL of ours, but they don't seem to be sending an input name along with the data.  Because I don't have a name to query on the receiving end (via PHP), I'm not sure how to get the data being sent.

For example, this is what is being used to send us the information:

```
xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>" _
  & "<update>" _
  & "<orderid>xxxx</orderid>" _
  & "<status>Received</status>" _
  & "<message></message>" _
  & "<laborderid>xxxxx</laborderid>" _
  & "</update>"
url = "https://xxxxxx"

set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", url, FALSE
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/atom+xml"
xmlhttp.send xml

response = xmlhttp.responseText
```

The line that confuses me is the "xmlhttp.send xml"; when just the XML string is being sent, how should we reference it in the receiving PHP file?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Input names are not always required as yours.
In such cases, you can read raw post data.

```
<?php
$xmlraw = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $xmlraw; // prints string of xml sent 
?>
```